# Acronis + unixware backup and restore

Tags: acronis

I want to use the Acronis in order to backup and restore UnixWare unix.
Please advice if Acronis can be used for UnixWare ?
I'm almost sure Acronis can backup/restore Linux but I am not sure about UnixWare.

Comment: In what capacity do you need it in?  Is it for workstations, servers, home?

Comment: I need to backup UnixWare machine , the disk is 36G , yes its server based on Pentium 3

Answer (score 1):

Acronis is mostly platform independent, meaning that it will work with most mainstream OSs (Linux, Windows, **Unixware**, etc).

Personally, I have [Backup & Recovery](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/online/#features) for my servers which should be what you are looking for.  Acronis is nice in that they will let you try the software before you shovel out the cash to purchase a full license so that you can see it is a good fit for you.

Should you go against getting Acronis, [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/business/theme.jsp?themeid=backupexec-family) and [EMC](http://www.emc.com/replication/recoverpoint/recoverpoint.htm) would be worth looking at for your situation.

Comment: please advice how Acronis shuld work , I have unixware machine connected to switch so acronis shuld work on other windows machine as client? or I need to download the acronis software in my PC card (PC card is like USB in my unixware machine ?)

Comment: Advice: Find someone who knows what they're doing to help you. My apologies for being blunt, but you quite obviously are below the threshold where we can help you via the Internet. It's time to hire a local consultant who knows how to get your network where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though it depends on what kernel your UnixWare machine is running. According to http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/server-linux/#requirements, the newest version works with Linux with kernel 2.4.20 or later and glibc 2.3.2 or later.

With Acronis Backup & Recovery you can install the software agent on the server and administer the software via the server (Manage this machine). Alternatively, you can connect to the machine via the Acronis Management console and set up your backups that way from a central location.

You can hook up a local drive / tape drive to the server being backed up, or you can backup to a network device as well.

Hope that helps.